# Alternative to Lambda?

Tags: python, lambda, turtle-graphics

Lambda functions scare me.

I adapted some code that used one to make this program for exploring the strategy for "the 21 Game".

Could someone please explain how to replace the lambda with a more simple construct? As far as I can tell, [`onclick()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.onclick) doesn't allow additional arguments.

I will eventually learn about lambdas properly, but I also want to share this code with students who certainly aren't ready for them.

```
import turtle

TURTLE_SIZE = 20
SQUARE_SIZE = 20

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(600,200)
screen.title("The 21 Game")
screen.bgcolor("black")

board = ['?'] * 21

screen.tracer(0)

for i in range(21):
    box = turtle.Turtle('square', visible=False)
    box.shapesize(SQUARE_SIZE / TURTLE_SIZE)
    box.color('Red')
    box.penup()
    box.goto(-220 + i * (SQUARE_SIZE + 2), 0)
    box.showturtle()
    box.stamp()

    board[i] = box
    box.onclick(lambda x, y, box=box, i=i: mouse(box, i))

screen.tracer(1)

def mouse(box, i):
    if box.color()[0] == "Red":
        box.color("Green")
    else:
        box.color("Red")

turtle.done()
```

Comment: *Lambda functions scare me* - if they scare you - define a regular function, you have an example even by that link you've posted

Comment: Sure, but how do I pass the `box` and `i` parameters to the `mouse` function?

Comment: Lambda functions aren't a thing. Lambda *expressions* are just expressions that define `function` objects. There's no significant difference between functions defined by `lambda` expressions and functions defined by `def` statements.

Comment: @chepner: One arguably significant difference is functions defined by lambda expressions don't have a unique name.

Comment: @martineau I don't consider that a significant difference. Metaprogramming and introspection aside, that doesn't affect how the function works. (I don't remember the last time I cared what a function's name was.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not much to a `lambda` expression. It just defines a function by providing a single expression to use as the return value. Any function you can define with a `lambda` expression can be defined with a `def` statement.

Shown inside the loop, `lambda x, y, box=box, i=i: mouse(box, i)` becomes

```
for i in range(21):
    box = turtle.Turtle('square', visible=False)

    ...

    def my_func(x, y, box=box, i=i):
        return mouse(box, i)

    box.onclick(my_func)
```

Comment: should be noted that the function is defined **inside** the loop

Comment: The fact that this code needs to be inside the loop highlights some confusion I still have - how come `my_func` needs to be defined multiple times?

Comment: Actually I can see that it's probably because the values of `box` and `i` need updating each time. However, I've not seen this pattern before and it seems something quite subtle is going on - not sue if I could have figured it out on my own. Any clarifying insights please?

Comment: @robin: Actually it's a fairly well-know technique and has been around a long time. e.g. [The extra arguments trick](http://web.archive.org/web/20130613111836/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/extra-args.html)

Comment: Each time through the loop, you are defining a brand new function, based on the current values of `box` and `i`. It only looks like the "same" function because you are binding it to the same name (`my_func`) each time. One reason to use a lambda expression is that you only need that name once, when you pass the function as an argument to `box.onclick`. The lambda expression lets you pass the function immediately, without first binding it to an otherwise unnecessary name.

Answer (score 1):

I might consider using `functools.partial` in this situation.  Below's my rework of your code using this function and a number of other changes to consider:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle, mainloop
from functools import partial

TURTLE_SIZE = 20
SQUARE_SIZE = 20
COLOR_MAP = {'red': 'green', 'green': 'red'}

def mouse(x, y, box):
    box.fillcolor(COLOR_MAP[box.fillcolor()])

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(600, 200)
screen.title("The 21 Game")
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.tracer(0)

board = []

for i in range(21):
    box = Turtle('square')
    box.shapesize(SQUARE_SIZE / TURTLE_SIZE)
    box.color('black', 'red')
    box.penup()
    box.setx(-220 + i * SQUARE_SIZE)
    box.onclick(partial(mouse, box=box))

    board.append(box)

screen.tracer(1)
mainloop()
```

The `partial` function creates a new function that locks in your `box` argument.  (I didn't see a purpose yet for the `i` argument, but you can add it to the `partial` call if really needed.)

I've eliminated the 2 pixel border by enabling the turtle's own outline via `pencolor` vs. `fillcolor`.  (You can adjust the size of this as an argument to `shapesize()`.)  You don't need to `stamp()` as your turtles aren't going anywhere -- unless there's more to this game.  (Similarly, I don't see the purpose to `board` unless there's more to this game.)  You don't need `visible=False` and `showturtle()` since all that code is under a `tracer(0)` anyway.

(I handled `mainloop` in the manner above so that this can run under either Python 2 or Python 3.)

Comment: While your mastery of the `turtle` graphics module is laudable, in this context I think it's mostly a distraction.

Comment: @martineau, the OP stated, "I also want to share this code with students".  When I write code examples for *my* students, I aim to remove *noise* to allow them to focus on the feature presented.  No-ops in the code is one thing I consider to be noise.  Among other things.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace `box.onclick(lambda x, y, box=box, i=i: mouse(box, i))` with:

```
def mouse_callback(box, i):
    def action(x, y):
        mouse(box, i)
    return action
box.onclick(mouse_callback(box, i))
```

Now, now, don't tell me nested scopes scare you too.

Comment: Seems unnecessarily complex.

Comment: should be noted that the function is defined **outside** the loop

Comment: @Tomerikoo For efficiency only. It could be defined within the loop with no effect other than some wasted allocation of functions.

Comment: @martineau Not really when you realize that it is really a class definition in disguise `box.onclick(Box(box, i).action)`.

Comment: @DanD. yeah I mainly pointed that out to show the difference between the two approaches (yours and @chepner's)

Comment: @Dan: Realize it's really a class definition? `import this`